# Python odd way of declaring a class with a name after the colon

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I have seen somewhere the use of the following syntax:

```
class MyClass : AnotherClass
```

What does this mean? Is this inheritance without the use of MyClass(AnotherClass):?

Comment: Some real example you see?

Comment: In other languages in would be used to specify the parent class (C++, C#). Because of how python is structured, a colon like this would mean that AnotherClass is in the body of the class, and that the class only has 1 line. Based on this it couldn't exist in python.

Comment: @TBell So do you think someone meant to write `class MyClass(AnotherClass):` but just forgot the Python syntax? It'd help to see a real example; like if `MyClass` has more to its body and uses methods defined in `AnotherClass` on itself, that'd confirm.

Answer (score 1):

After the colon i.e. the `Class` definition comes the building element of the `Class`:

> ```
> class ClassName:
>     <statement-1>
>     .
>     .
>     .
>     <statement-N>
> ```

So `AnotherClass` means nothing here itself and does nothing with inheritances.

The syntax:

```
class MyClass : AnotherClass
```

is the same like:

```
class MyClass: 
    AnotherClass
```

It could be an instantiation in the form:

```
a = AnotherClass()
```